# How to trigger UIButton from another class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I have two view controllers linked by button1. viewController1 contains button1. viewController2 is triggered by button1. viewController2 contains button2. **How can I trigger button2 from button1?**

Comment: Invoke from code or from storyboard?

Comment: What does that mean, "trigger"? Button 2 calls some method. So you can call that method from anywhere. Just call it.

Comment: Write common code in appDelegate

Comment: @matt What I want the app to do is more complicated than that. Calling the button simplifies my code tremendously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it programmatically by writing this:

```
[_button sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

But you question is confusing. You said **viewController2 is triggered by button1**, why do you need this? Did you know about protocol? Can protocol serve your need? See the [Apples Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html).

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Don't.

In general, you should treat a view controllers views (and buttons are views) as private. If you want to get a view controller to do something for you, you should add a method to that view controller that does what you want, and then call it.

Mucking around with a view controller's view hierarchy violates the principle of encapsulation, an important OOD (Object Oriented Design) concept. Among other bad things, it makes your program fragile, because if in the future you decide to change the UI of viewController1 and move buttons around, you can easily break view controller 2.

In this case it could be as simple as putting the IBAction for the button in the .h file, and then calling the action. The only gotcha there is if the IBAction method needs the sender parameter to point to the button. You may be able to pass in a sender of nil and write your action method to handle a nil sender.

Another option is to pull the code that actually does the work for the button out into a separate method, and have the button's IBAction code call that method, and have your other view controller call it as well. That also makes your intentions clearer and makes your code more self-documenting. Six months later (or 6 years later!) you might not remember that an outside view controller calls one of viewController1's IBAction methods, and probably wouldn't expect it. A public non-IBAction method, though, is part of your object's "contract", and you should expect outside objects to call it.